# Google Docs Viewer to read your pdf online - Android

Tags: android, android-webview

Android PDF reader inside the `web-view`

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Is this reliable, if google changes the URL?

Comment: If Google changes the URL, you should be able to provide an update with the new URL. But I don't think, the URL will change without any redirection or preannouncement.

Comment: As the application will be fed with the hard-coded URL, re-direction is acceptable, but pre-anouncement should definitely release a new build with this change.